# How to get all fields in a wizard page?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a wizard page with many text fields. Now I want to do similar  operation like setToolTip for all these fields. The tooltip is same for all. So I was wondering if I could get all widgets in page, then check if they are text field, if it is text field set tool tip. This would avoid me having to write similar line of code for all text fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recurse through the controls in the page with something like:

```
Composite body = (Composite)getControl();

findText(body);

...

private void findText(Composite composite)
{
  Control [] children = composite.getChildren();
  if (children == null || children.length == 0)
    return;

  for (Control child : children)
   {
     if (child == null || child.isDisposed())
       continue;

     if (child instanceof Composite)
       findText((Composite)child);

     if (child instanceof Text)
      {
        ... handle Text control
      }  
   } 
}
```